# What JDBC batch delete strategy is best for performance?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I need to perform batch deletes using JDBC and based on ID keys. But, what is the best method in sake of performance?

Method 1:

```
var preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN ?");
preparedStatement.setArray(1, idsToDelete);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Method 2:

```
var preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = ?");
for(var id : idsToDelete){
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Which one is best practice and/or better for performance?
The DBMS is PostgreSQL 12 running in Ubuntu server inside the LAN.

Comment: I think the answer would depend on the database engine, so the usual answer for performance questions applies: Test it.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I've updated the question, its PostgreSQL 12 running in an ubuntu server inside the LAN. I'll try to test.

Comment: I would be astonished if the first wasn't many times faster than the second, given a large enough set of IDs to delete.